# Unable to find provider assembly with name MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have created a new project based on mvc core 2.0 on Framework 4.6.x.
I want to do dbFirst with MySql DataBase.
I followed the steps that define the MySql official website.

Scaffolding to Database Using Package Manager Console in Visual Studio.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html

Once all the steps have been executed I have executed the Scaffold-DbContext in the Package Manager Console
After a few seconds, the following error occurs:

**Unable to find provider assembly with name MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. Ensure the specified name is correct and referenced by the project.**

I have seen solutions for SQLServer but not for MySql.

Thank you.

Comment: Same question for me! Do you have the solution?

Comment: so at the moment mysql has not taken official pluguin, at this time are the test and apparently do not work well.
I am currently working with entity framework 6.

Comment: please see this, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install package

> Install-Package MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 8.0.13

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same problem and my solution was:

Set startup project (should not be a library project type) and target project, then make sure I have already install all of the packages.

For MySQL I was using [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)

```
   <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
```

This command to generate the database  [dotnet ef dbcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=password;database=dbname;" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -o Models  -p targetproject -s startup project
```

Answer (score 1):

When wrestling with tooling, there can be a variety of issues. In my case, I was attempting to reverse-engineer into a .NET Standard Class Library project. This is not supported. I had not yet set the library as a dependency to another project.

If this is your situation: reference the class library from an executable project. Reference the executable project from `Scaffold-DbContext` (using `-Project` or setting it as the default) and it should run. By default it will generate the code files into the executable project, so you should use the [other switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext) as needed, or you can just copy them over and change the namespaces as necessary.